# how to put a figure inside paragraph

Tags: html

```
<p>
    <figure style="display:inline;">
        <img src="images/testing.jpg" style="float:right;"/>
        <figcaption>Test</figcaption>
    </figure>
    Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt.
</p>
```

I'm expecting the image to be located to the right of the paragraph and there to be a caption under the image. I am getting the image located correctly but the caption located on top of the paragraph

Answer (score 0):

Transfer the text of your paragraph

```
<p>
    Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt.
    <figure style="display:inline;">
        <img src="images/testing.jpg" style="float:right;"/>
       <figcaption>Test</figcaption>
    </figure>
</p>
```